# Rails: How to search two columns by the value of check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to search two columns by the value of one check box.

`steps` model has `place1` and `place2` columns.

```
class CreateSteps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :steps do |t|
      t.integer :place1
      t.integer :place2
      t.integer :time

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I can search only one columns. The view is as following.

```
<%= form_tag(steps_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form2") do %>
    <% @places.each do |p| %>
        <%= check_box_tag('place[place1][]', p.id) %>
        <%= label_tag(p.id, p.id)%>
    <% end %><br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<% if @choices.present? %>

    <% @choices.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.place1 %>, <%= c.place2 %>, <%= c.time %><br>
    <% end %>

<% else %>
  <p>not exist</p>
<% end %>
```

The controller as following;

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @places = Place.all

    if params[:place]
      @choices = Step.where(steps: params[:place]).order(time: :asc)
    end

  end

end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

**EDIT**

My view image is as following;

```
[ ] check box 1
[ ] check box 2
[ ] check box 3
[ ] check box 4
[ ] check box 5

[Seach button]
```

Sample records are as followings;

```
Place1 place2
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
2           3
2           4
2           5
3           4 
3           5
4           5
```

If checkbox 2, 4 and 5 are checked, my expectation values are three records; {2, 4}, {2, 5} and {4, 5}.

If checkbox 1, 3, 4 and 5 are checked, my expectation values are six records; {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5} and {4, 5}.

Answer (score 0):

User selection for places checkboxes should be stored in an array of `params[:place][:place1]`. To make things clearer i would rename that to `params[:place][:places]` by setting the name in view to `place[places][]`.

So in the controller we can do:

```
place1, place2 = params[:place][:places] if params[:place]
@choices = Step.where(place1: place1, place2: place2).order(time: :asc)
```

Side Note:

- I can't say i fully understand the `places` relation but it feels a bit off with `place1` and `place2`. First problem i could imagine is order, how you guarantee correct mapping between places pulled from `Place` model to match `place1` and `place2`?  Did you consider making a `has_many` relation, i think that could make filtering easier?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Nimir. I edit my post (second half of the post) and add image that I'd like to do. Thank you for your time.